# ValueError: Invalid classes inferred from unique values of `y` in XGBoost

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, xgboost

I'm new to the Data Science field and I'm trying to apply XGBoost in a table having 5 rows × 46 columns

and my last column is my target column.

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install xgboost
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x=df_null_mean.iloc[:,:-1]
y=df_null_mean.iloc[:,-1]
x_cols=x.columns

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

# Fitting XGBoost to the training data
my_model = xgb.XGBClassifier()
my_model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

and the error I'm getting is

```
ValueError: Invalid classes inferred from unique values of `y`.  Expected: [  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17
  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35
  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53
  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71
  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89
  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107
 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125
 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143
 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161
 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179
 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197
 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215
 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233
 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251
 252 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 269
 270 271 272 273 274 275 276 277 278 279 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 287
 288 289 290 291 292 293 294 295 296 297 298 299 300 301 302 303 304 305
 306 307 308 309 310 311 312 313 314 315 316 317 318 319 320 321 322 323
 324 325 326 327 328 329 330 331 332 333 334 335 336 337 338 339 340 341
 342 343 344 345 346 347 348 349 350 351 352 353 354 355 356 357 358 359
 360 361 362 363 364 365 366 367 368 369 370 371 372 373 374 375 376 377
 378 379 380 381 382 383 384 385 386 387 388 389 390 391 392 393 394 395
 396 397 398 399 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413
 414 415 416 417 418 419 420 421 422 423 424 425 426 427 428 429 430 431
 432 433 434 435 436 437 438 439 440 441 442 443 444 445 446 447 448 449
 450 451 452 453 454 455 456 457 458 459 460 461 462 463 464 465 466 467
 468 469 470 471 472 473 474 475 476 477 478 479 480 481 482 483 484 485
 486 487 488 489 490 491 492 493 494 495 496 497 498 499 500 501 502 503
 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 512 513 514 515 516 517 518 519 520 521
 522 523 524 525 526 527 528 529 530 531 532 533 534 535 536 537 538 539
 540 541 542 543 544 545 546 547 548 549 550 551 552 553 554 555 556 557
 558 559 560 561 562 563 564 565 566 567 568 569 570 571 572 573 574 575
 576 577 578 579 580 581 582 583 584 585 586 587 588 589 590 591 592 593
 594 595 596 597 598 599 600 601 602 603 604 605 606 607 608 609 610 611
 612 613 614 615 616 617 618 619 620 621 622 623 624 625 626 627 628 629
 630 631 632 633 634 635 636 637 638 639 640 641 642 643 644 645 646 647
 648 649 650 651 652 653], got [  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17
  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35
  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53
  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71
  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89
  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107
 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125
 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143
 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161
 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179
 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197
 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215
 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233
 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251
 252 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 269
 270 271 272 273 274 275 276 277 278 279 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 287
 288 289 290 291 292 293 294 295 296 297 298 299 300 301 302 303 304 305
 306 307 308 309 310 311 312 313 314 315 316 317 318 319 320 321 322 323
 324 325 326 327 328 329 330 331 332 333 334 335 336 337 338 339 340 341
 342 343 344 345 346 347 348 349 350 351 352 353 354 355 356 357 358 359
 360 361 362 363 364 365 366 367 368 369 370 371 372 373 374 375 376 377
 378 379 380 381 382 383 384 385 386 387 388 389 390 391 392 393 394 395
 396 397 398 399 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413
 414 415 416 417 418 419 420 421 422 423 424 425 426 427 428 429 430 431
 432 433 434 435 436 437 438 439 440 441 442 443 444 445 446 447 448 449
 450 451 452 453 454 455 456 457 458 459 460 461 462 463 464 465 466 467
 468 469 470 471 472 473 474 475 476 477 478 479 480 481 482 483 484 485
 486 487 488 489 490 491 492 493 494 495 496 497 498 499 500 501 502 503
 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 512 513 514 515 516 517 518 519 520 521
 522 523 524 525 526 527 528 529 530 531 532 533 534 535 536 537 538 539
 540 541 542 544 545 546 547 548 549 550 551 553 554 555 556 557 558 559
 560 562 563 564 565 567 568 569 570 572 573 574 576 577 578 579 580 581
 582 583 584 585 586 587 588 589 590 591 592 593 595 596 598 599 602 605
 606 607 608 609 614 615 617 619 622 626 628 629 630 631 632 638 639 640
 642 647 650 659 665 673 674 680 684 685 688 691 703 710 713 714 715 716
 717 718 719 727 730 731 763 786 812 850 854 857 862 870 876 878 880 884
 889 892 894 898 900 902]
```

Can anyone help me with the resolution?

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install xgboost
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x=df_null_mean.iloc[:,:-1]
y=df_null_mean.iloc[:,-1]
x_cols=x.columns

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

# Fitting XGBoost to the training data
my_model = xgb.XGBClassifier()
my_model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to have the class numerotated from 0 to `n-1` where n is your number of class.
Try this:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
y_train = le.fit_transform(y_train)
```